# goBack re render in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i am new to react native,i am using goBack() in react navigation. My Previous Screen Component Rendering again,  I don't want to rerender again.

```
<Header>
          <Left>
            <Icon name="menu" onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.goBack(null) } />
          </Left>
      </Header>
```

can you please help me on this

Comment: are you using stackNavigator right?

Comment: `this.props.navigation.goBack(null)` is similar to the back button in the browser it won't re-render the components it will show the cached data

Comment: @RaajNadar i am already using it, but it again re render the component

Comment: yes i am using the stackNavigator inside drawernavigator